# Two multiselect fields on the same page are corrupted, vue multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, multi-select

I am using this [vue.js solution](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-multiple-select) for multiselect drop-down menu.
I am trying to have two multiselect fields on the same page. They reflect different datasets. Yet selection in the second one is corrupted.

```
<div id="app">
  <multiselect 
    placeholder="Select"
    v-model="value" 
    :options="options"
    :multiple="true"
    track-by="language"
    label="language"
    >
  </multiselect>
  <pre>{{ value }}</pre>

  <multiselect 
    placeholder="Select"
    v-model="value2" 
    :options="options2"
    :multiple="true"
    track-by="language"
    label="language"
    >
  </multiselect>
  <pre>{{ value2 }}</pre>
</div>
```

Vue.js:

```
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
    },
    data: {
    value: {language: 'aaa'},
    options: [
      { language: 'aaa'},
      { language: 'bbb'},
      { language: 'ccc'}
    ],
    options2: [
    {   language: '111'},
      { language: '222'},
      { language: '333'}
    ]
    },
  methods: {
    onSelect (items, lastSelectItem) {
      this.items = items
      this.lastSelectItem = lastSelectItem
    },
    // deselect option
    reset () {
      this.items = [] // reset
    },
    // select option from parent component
    selectOption () {
      this.items = _.unionWith(this.items, [this.options[0]], _.isEqual)
    },
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Try it out here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmfwavgo/)

How can I make both multiselects work separately from each other?

EDIT: [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/sxyugL9p/)

Comment: You forgot to initialize `value2`, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/yu1ja2t8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `value2` data field.

Add `value2: {language: 'bbb'},` and it should work

Comment: yes, I just found it, was going to delete the question :)

Comment: Oh leave it, might be useful some time again ;)